# Getting output very slow

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After running the code the data it is extracting is very slow, is there any other method to fetch the data in faster way?Is there any other method without using selenium in faster way.I have already extracted the links,i am fetching the data from links stored in csv.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

data_file = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Arun kumar\\Desktop\\genexehr1.csv')
for count in range(0,5001):
    link = data_file.iloc[count,0]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')   
    data = soup.find('div',class_='content')
    try:
        name = data.find('h1',class_='title')
        print "NAME:"+name.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "NAME:NA"
    try:
        contact = data.find('h3',class_="title1 docdetallocation")
        print "CONTACT:"+contact.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "CONTACT:NA"
    try:
        Qual = soup.find('h3',class_="title1")
        print "QUALIFICATION:"+Qual.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "QUALIFICATION:NA"        
    try:
        Spec = data.find('div',class_='text')
        print "SPECIALIZATION:"+Spec.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "SPECIALIZATION:NA"      
    try:
        data1= soup.find('div',class_='contactdetailsbox')
        hos = data1.find('div',class_='heading').find('a')
        print "HOSPITAL:"+hos.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "HOSPITAL:NA"
    try:
        data2= soup.find('div',class_='contactdetailsbox')
        add = data2.find('div',class_='title1 margin-top-10')
        print "ADDRESS:"+add.text.replace('\n','').strip()
    except:
        print "ADDRESS:NA"

    print "LINK:"+link

driver.close()
```

Comment: Move `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` out of the loop, you don't need new driver every time. Some sites have API which provide a way to get data with requests, but I don't know if that is the case in your sites. But you still have 5000 urls to check, it will take some time either way.

Comment: You will probably gett better results posting this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/